# ML model error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, flask, scikit-learn

I was trying to make a predictive model, but I can't find a way to solve this numpy-related issue with my code. I already imported the pickle file containing the model I saved from Google Colab, but I can't seem to make it work. Any type of response will be appreciated!

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pickle
import numpy as np
import joblib

model = pickle.load(open('model_car_price', 'rb'))

joblib.dump(model,'model_car_prices_data')

# imported the pickle file containing the ML model
realmodel = pickle.load(open('model_car_prices_data', 'rb'))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True


@app.route('/')
def man():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def home():
    data1 = request.form['a']
    data2 = request.form['b']
    data3 = request.form['c']
    data4 = request.form['d']
    data5 = request.form['e']
    data6 = request.form['f']
    data7 = request.form['g']
    arr = np.array([[data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7]])
    pred = model.predict(arr)
    return render_template('after.html', data=pred)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: looks like `model` is a np.array. Are you sure you saved the right object, or did you accidentally overwrite that object with a numpy array when you were debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Try typing

```
type(model)
```

pickle.load seems to be returning an numpy array